# Convert this Java 8 DSL to non-Java 8

Tags: spring-integration

I'm just starting to use Spring integration DSL after using the XML namespace for a few years.

I like the DSL but my lack of Java 8 knowledge is hindering me.

For example how would you write the following example code in Java 7, I'm confused by the `e -> e.id("sendMailEndpoint"))` as I can't work out what type `e` is!

```
   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow sendMailFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sendMailChannel")
            .handle(Mail.outboundAdapter("localhost")
                            .port(smtpPort)
                            .credentials("user", "pw")
                            .protocol("smtp")
                            .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "true")),
                    e -> e.id("sendMailEndpoint"))
            .get();
   }
```

Kind regards

David/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David, any Lambda is inline functional interface implementation.
If you take a look to the source code (or at least JavaDocs) of that `.handle()` method, you'll see that `e` param is `Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<H>>`, so for non-Java 8 environment you just should implement that interface on the place:

```
 .handle(Mail.outboundAdapter("localhost")
                        .port(smtpPort)
                        .credentials("user", "pw")
                        .protocol("smtp")
                        .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "true")),
                new Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<MailSendingMessageHandler>>() {

                            @Override
                            public void accept(GenericEndpointSpec<MailSendingMessageHandler> e) {
                                e.id("sendMailEndpoint");
                            }
                })
```

The same is for `javaMailProperties`.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I do have some understanding of Lambda's and the properties one was fine. Trouble I had was with the Consumer class and all of the options you had for the Consumer type and then further options for the GenericEndpointSpec type.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to ask more or provide feedback. For example I'm going to rework `.aggregate(aggregatorConfigurer, endpointConfigurer)` just to single `configurer` which accepts options for `AggregatingMessageHandler` as well as for its `endpoint`. Maybe the same would make sense for those protocol-specific `Specs` like `Mail.outboundAdapter`.